# LaTeX cannot find my local style file even though it is in my local ls-R file

Tags: errors, pdftex, texmf

I am attempting to use the `revtex4-2.cls` style file.  It is in my local `texmf` tree:

> (base) :~/myhome/texmf/latex/revtex 
> $ ls revtex4-2.cls 
> revtex4-2.cls

My `TEXMFHOME` environment variable is set:

> $ echo $TEXMFHOME 
> ~/myhome/texmf

The `revtex4-2.cls` file is in `ls_R`

> ./latex/revtex: 
> revtex4-1.cls 
> revtex4-2.cls 
> sor4-2.rtx

But when I run `pdflatex`, I get:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `revtex4-2.cls' not found.

Comment: Texmf/latex is wrong, the path should be texmf/tex/latex

Comment: Ulrike Fischer, could you please make that an answer?  That was the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `.../texmf/latex` is wrong, the path should be `...texmf/tex/latex`.